# Attempted import error: my file does not contain a default export?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am having an issue with a react project im working on

my authHelper is not being imported correctly into a privateRoute component im making. Im a bit of a newb and going off a book I purchased called full stack react projects from Pakkt. I noticed the book has issues all over it with incorrect imports and exports

here is the code below

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from  '../../helpers/authHelper.js';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    
    <Route {...rest} render={props => {
        
        auth.isAuthenticated() ? ( 
            <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/authentication/card', 
            state: { from: props.location }}} >    
            </Redirect>
        )
        }} />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

here is the authHelper

```
import axios from "axios"



 const signout = async () => {
      try {
            let response = await axios.get('auth/signout', {method: 'GET' })
            return await response.json()
        }   catch (err) {
              console.log(err)
      }
    }
   const authenticate = (jwt, cb) => {
    if(typeof window !== "undefined")
    sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', JSON.stringify(jwt))
    cb()
}

   const isAuthenticated = () => {
      
    if(typeof window == "undefined")
    return false

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('jwt'))
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('jwt'))
    else
      return false
}

  const clearJWT = (cb) => {
    if(typeof window !== "undefined")
    sessionStorage.removeitem('jwt')
    cb()
    signout().then((data) => {
        document.cookie = "t=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;"
    })
}

export { isAuthenticated, authenticate, clearJWT}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
in PrivateRoute.js I changed

import auth from '../../helpers/authHelper.js'

to

const auth = require('../../helpers/authHelper.js')

There was also another error in PrivateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => { //this curly brace needs to be ( instead of {
    
    <Route {...rest} render={props => { this needs to be a ( instead of {
        
        auth.isAuthenticated() ? ( 
            <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/authentication/card', 
            state: { from: props.location }}} >    
            </Redirect>
        )
} //this Curley brace to left needs to be a ) instead of } //} />
} // this needs to be changed to a ) instead of }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default { isAuthenticated, authenticate, clearJWT }

or 

export const ()=>{}

And 
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (    
    <Route {...rest} render={props => {
        
        auth.isAuthenticated() ? ( 
            <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/authentication/card', 
            state: { from: props.location }}} >    
            </Redirect>
        )
        }} />
)
```